# Raspberry Pi Zero detecting too many i2c

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w, sensor

After this command in raspberry pi

```
 i2cdetect -y 1
```

Its detects too many i2cs

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 
10: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 
20: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f 
30: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f 
40: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f 
50: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f 
60: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f 
70: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
```

Any solutions? Hardware is raspberry pi zero and sensor is Mpu6050

Comment: You have the SDA line shorted to ground.